# Figuring out what this function does?

Tags: c

I have to rewrite this for loop into a do while loop, but I can't figure out what this does. Please help

```
for(;; done = (int) sum == 5
{if (done) break;
sum += 2.6;}
```

Comment: I dont think this is syntactically correct.

Comment: On a lighter node: since this does not compile, write anything you want, not going to make a difference.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] and read this: [ask] and this: [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that the syntax error is resolved, so that the code reads

```
for(;; done = (int) sum == 5)
{
    if (done) break;
    sum += 2.6;
}
```

Now this code works as follows: the `for` loop has no initialization expression and no test expression, so it begins execution unconditionally. The first thing that happens is the "flag" `done` (an undefined object that I'm assuming is an `int` that may or may not be initialized to zero) is checked. If it's true (non-zero), the code breaks out of the `for` loop. if not, 2.6 (a `double`) is added to `sum` (an undefined object that I'm assuming is a `double` and that may or may not be initialized to a sensible value, or a number at all). When execution reaches the closing brace, the iteration statement in the `for` loop is executed, which compares `sum` to 5 (after converting `sum` to an integer value), and assigns the result of the comparison (i.e. 1 for true and 0 for false) to `done`.

Converting this to a `while` loop ought to be fairly straightforward. Simply execute these steps in order. Note that since the first piece of code to execute is checking `if(done)`, the code more naturally lends itself to a simple `while` than a `do-while` loop.

Note that this would have been considerably clearer if you had defined the types of your variables, and provided initial values for them.

Comment: @Raffael Please make the answer by Tim as the solution if you are satisfied with the answer. So that the question can be closed.

Comment: @Tim you were correct about the sum being a double. Sum and done were defined as 0.0 and 0 respectively.

Comment: Minor correction: `(int)sum == 5` parses as `((int)sum) == 5`, not `(int)(sum == 5)`